# Canceling Unnamed, Non-Unique Periodic WorkRequests in Android WorkManager

Tags: android, android-workmanager

In a previous iteration of our application, we implemented a periodic task using WorkManager as follows:

```java
WorkManager.getInstance(context).enqueue(
    new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(OurClassName.class, 8, TimeUnit.HOURS)
        .setConstraints(constraints)
        .setInputData(OurClassName.getParameterBundle())
        .build()
);
```

This code snippet schedules a job that executes every 8 hours.

However, we've encountered an issue where these tasks cannot be canceled since they were not assigned a unique 'name' or 'tag'.

Complicating matters, due to a bug, this scheduling code was executed every time the app launched, resulting in a significant accumulation of identical, scheduled jobs.

Despite attempting to use both `WorkManager` and `JobScheduler`'s `cancelAll` methods as a broad-stroke solution, the jobs persist.

How can we effectively cancel these periodically scheduled tasks, especially considering they lack unique identifiers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> We've encountered an issue where these tasks cannot be canceled since they were not assigned a unique 'name' or 'tag'.

The `WorkRequest` created by the `.build()` function can be used to fetch the `id` to manage its operation via WorkManager instance.
Example:

```kotlin
val periodicWorker = new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(OurClassName.class, 8, TimeUnit.HOURS)
        .setConstraints(constraints)
        .setInputData(OurClassName.getParameterBundle())
        .build()

val workId = periodicWorker.id;
```

> Complicating matters, due to a bug, this scheduling code was executed every time the app launched, resulting in a significant accumulation of identical, scheduled jobs.

This is expected due to the use of `enqueue`. Using `enqueueUniquePeriodicWork` would work as expected.

For cancellations, see: https://developer.android.com/develop/background-work/background-tasks/persistent/how-to/manage-work#cancelling

---

Assuming you need to cancel all the previous `WorkRequest`s (say on a new app update), you can use - `WorkManager.getInstance(context).cancelAllWork()` or `WorkManager.getInstance(context).cancelAllWorkById(workId)` if you have the IDs & then register the new WorkRequests via `enqueueUniquePeriodicWork`.

Disclaimer from the docs:

> Cancels all unfinished work. Use this method with extreme caution! By invoking it, you will potentially affect other modules or libraries in your codebase. It is strongly recommended that you use one of the other cancellation methods at your disposal.

Comment: Thanks @darshan but this does not help. Our code is already shipped, I can not get the IDS in retrospective.
Also - cancellation - as original question states - is not available unless you have the id, name or tag - which we do not have.

Comment: I assumed it was already shipped and hence I added the last point for cancelling all the work which doesn't really require any `tag` or `id`s on a new update. You can check on an update if there are existing workers. Last I know, the default tags for workers was something like this - `"$packageName.work_manager.workers"`.

Answer (score 0):

As it turned out, the aforementioned code, which does not specify a `tag` creates a enqueued job with a tag which equals to the full class name. i.e. in our example: `com.x.y.z.OurClassName`

Thus:

```java
WorkManager.getInstance(context).cancelAllWorkByTag("com.x.y.z.OurClassName");
```

Cancels old jobs, at least in testing on devices with Android 26+.

(The WorkManager uses different implementations per different underlying android versions)